Big difference of performance for the same query between two servers
I have an issue I can't understand. Im my company, we have 2 environments: TEST and PROD.
My TEST server has the following specs:
Intel Xeon-E 2388G - 8c/16t - 3.2 GHz/4.6 GHz
128 Go ECC 2933 MHz
2×512 Go SSD NVMe Soft RAID

My PROD server is way bigger:
Intel Xeon Gold 6312U - 24c/48t - 2.4 GHz/3.6 GHz
256 Go ECC 3200 MHz
2×1.92 To SSD NVMe Soft RAID


On both server, I have the same MySQL version:
===$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

mysql.conf file on TEST:
root@test:~# cat /etc/mysql-redacted/conf.d/redacted.cnf

# Chef generated my.cnf for instance mysql-redacted

[client]
default-character-set          = utf8
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.sock
ssl-ca                         = /etc/mysql-redacted/ca.pem
ssl-cert                       = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-cert.pem
ssl-key                        = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-key.pem


[mysql]
default-character-set          = utf8

[mysqld]
optimizer_switch               = 'index_merge=off'
slow_query_log                 = ON
long_query_time                = 5
slow_query_log_file            = /home/mysql/mysql/slow_query_log.log
wait_timeout                   = 604800
interactive_timeout            = 604800

skip_name_resolve
early-plugin-load              = keyring_file.so
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.sock
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
port                           = 3306
datadir                        = /home/mysql/mysql
max_allowed_packet             = 128M
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 110679M
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 256M

server-id                      = 1
binlog-format                  = mixed
log-bin                        = mysql-bin
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog                    = 1
auto-increment-increment       = 2
auto-increment-offset          = 1
ssl-ca                         = /etc/mysql-redacted/ca.pem
ssl-cert                       = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-cert.pem
ssl-key                        = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-key.pem
require-secure-transport       = ON
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql-redacted/error.log

binlog-format                  = mixed
log-bin                        = mysql-bin
relay-log                      = mysql-relay-bin
log-slave-updates              = 1
gtid-mode                      = ON
enforce-gtid-consistency

plugin-load-add=clone=mysql_clone.so


[mysqld_safe]
socket                         = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.sock

mysql.conf file on PROD:
root@gra-mysql-2-prod:/etc/mysql-redacted/conf.d# cat redacted.cnf

# Chef generated my.cnf for instance mysql-redacted

[client]
default-character-set          = utf8
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.sock
ssl-ca                         = /etc/mysql-redacted/ca.pem
ssl-cert                       = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-cert.pem
ssl-key                        = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-key.pem


[mysql]
default-character-set          = utf8

[mysqld]
optimizer_switch               = 'index_merge=off'
slow_query_log                 = ON
long_query_time                = 5
slow_query_log_file            = /home/mysql/mysql/slow_query_log.log

skip_name_resolve
early-plugin-load              = keyring_file.so
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.sock
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
port                           = 3306
datadir                        = /home/mysql/mysql
max_allowed_packet             = 128M
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 221347M
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 256M
server-id                      = 1
binlog-format                  = mixed
log-bin                        = mysql-bin
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog                    = 1
auto-increment-increment       = 2
auto-increment-offset          = 1
ssl-ca                         = /etc/mysql-redacted/ca.pem
ssl-cert                       = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-cert.pem
ssl-key                        = /etc/mysql-redacted/server-key.pem
require-secure-transport       = ON
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql-redacted/error.log

binlog-format                  = mixed
log-bin                        = mysql-bin
relay-log                      = mysql-relay-bin
log-slave-updates              = 1
gtid-mode                      = ON
enforce-gtid-consistency

plugin-load-add=clone=mysql_clone.so


[mysqld_safe]
socket                         = /run/mysql-redacted/mysqld.sockroot

The database from PROD is backup every night and restore on the TEST serveur.
On the TEST serveur size of the table called "entry" is 96G, on PROD it's 106G.
It has 137 columns.
The whole database is around 245G with 500 tables. Entry table is by far the biggest one.
I have an SQL request which select all fields from the table entry for 7000+ ids. (This request is to compare performance, nothing else)
select * from entry where ID in (xxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxx)


On my TEST server, the result of
source test.sql

7589 rows in set, 1 warning (27.12 sec)

On my production server:
7589 rows in set, 1 warning (56.40 sec)

Results are the same if I execute the same query multiple times.
It takes twice the time for the request to execute on a serveur which is way more powerful. I'm not an SQL expert, far from that, but I would expect to have at least the same results between both servers.
I check the performance graph on both servers, didn't find any bottleneck (which does not means it does not exists).
My question is, what could cause such difference, or how can I find the source of these difference and hopefully fix them ?
If additional details are needed, please let me know. Any hint would be highly appreciated.
DeWaRs.
Edit 1:
The EXPLAIN ANALYZE for PROD return:
| -> Filter: (entry.id in (XXXXX,XXXXX,XXXXXX))

 (cost=5.29e+6 rows=2.82e+6) (actual time=13871..55887 rows=7589 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on entry  (cost=5.29e+6 rows=5.64e+6) (actual time=0.0702..54921 rows=9.08e+6 loops=1)

Edit 2:
The EXPLAIN ANALYZE for TEST return:
| -> Filter: (entry.id in (XXXXXX,XXXXX,XXXX))
 (cost=5.21e+6 rows=4.25e+6) (actual time=14005..133534 rows=7589 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on entry  (cost=5.21e+6 rows=8.49e+6) (actual time=0.0392..132955 rows=9.08e+6 loops=1)


Are your queries being executed in parallel? On TEST and PROD?
Run the statements with the addition EXPLAIN ANALYZE and add the execution plans to your question:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from entry where ID in (xxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxx);

Possible Causes

Your single thread performance is better on the TEST server than on your PROD server. If the statement isn't running in parallel, then the TEST server could be faster, because of the single thread performance:
Intel Xeon E-2388G @ 3.20GHz (PassMark Software | CPU Benchmark)
Intel Xeon Gold 6312U @ 2.40GHz (Passmark Software | CPU Benchmark)
Why is this?
Well a single thread running at 5.1 GHz is faster than a single thread running at 3.6 GHz. (see benchmark details; Turbo Speed)

Is your PROD environment an actual productive environment? Are there other users querying the database? There you go. Another possible reason.

Other reasons may become obvious as soon as we have the details of the execution plans.



I have update my initial message with then EXLPAIN ANALYZE for PROD, TEST will be updated later.

That is a good hint ...
PROD is real prod, but I tested the query during the night where there is no other users, with the same results.

